# send audio to speakers and headphone

Tags: java, javasound

I have a code that capture an audio and it have an if statement for the source of the input audio, if it was from the speaker or a headset.

I want to add to this if statement in which every time I receive the audio from the headphone then it should be sent to my phone (I was recording to make sure if I receive the audio or not) from the speaker through aux auxiliary cable..

And vise verse, every time I receive it from the speaker then it should be sent to the headphone

This is what I have done so far, but when I play it

firstly, it does not send the audio through the speaker (the recorder in my phone didn't record the audio, it record normally and I don't know if the problem with the way of testing it or it does not receive the audio)

secondly, when I played it on my computer it play the first line of the array then it pause for a few seconds before it play the next line

so what exactly I want is to know how can I send the audio to the speaker and the headphone 
and a way to avoid or reduce the delay while playing the audio as much as possible

```
private void captureAudio() {
 if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.HEADPHONE)) {
        try {
            final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(
                    TargetDataLine.class, format);
            final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();
            Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
                int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate()
                        * format.getFrameSize();
                byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
                public void run() {
                    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    running = true;
                    System.out.println("running..........");
                    int lines = 0;
                    try {
                        while (running) {
                            int count
                                    = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                            if (count > 0) {
                                lines++;
                                if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.SPEAKER)){
                                DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, getFormat());
                                SourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
                                SourceDataLine.open(getFormat());
                                SourceDataLine.start();
                                SourceDataLine.write(buffer,0,count);
                                SourceDataLine.drain();
                                SourceDataLine.close();}
                            }
                        }
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("I/O problems: " + e);
                        System.exit(-1);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Ee2e.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            };
            Thread captureThread = new Thread(runner);
            captureThread.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.err.println("Line unavailable: " + e);
            System.exit(-2);
        }

      }
} else if ((AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.SPEAKER))) {

        try {
            final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(
                    TargetDataLine.class, format);
            final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();

            Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
                int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate()
                        * format.getFrameSize();
                byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

                public void run() {
                    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    running = true;
                    System.out.println("running..........");
                    int lines = 0;
                    try {
                        while (running) {{
                            int count
                                    = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                            if (count > 0) {
                                lines++;
                                System.out.println("lines written =" + lines);
                                if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.HEADPHONE)){
                                DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, getFormat());                                    SourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
                                SourceDataLine.open(getFormat());
                                SourceDataLine.start();
                                SourceDataLine.write(buffer,0,count);
                                SourceDataLine.drain();
                                SourceDataLine.close();}
                            }

                        }

                        out.close();
                        }} catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("I/O problems: " + e);
                        System.exit(-1);
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Ee2e.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread captureThread = new Thread(runner);
            captureThread.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.err.println("Line unavailable: " + e);
            System.exit(-2);
        }
    } 
     else {
        System.out.println("wrong port");
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).